# how to detect the cases that fulfill A ∈ B, but B ∉ A

Tags: r

I have a dataset that looks like this:

[image]

It show the relationship among the dataset.
1). for col1, it means: all the variables in cy1.CSV are also in the dataset "cy1.CSV", "cy24.CSV", "cy6.CSV".
2) dov.CSV: all the variables in dov.CSV are also in the dataset "dov.CSV", "dov_1.CSV"
2) dov_1.CSV: all the variables in dov_1.CSV can only be found in the dataset "dov_1.CSV"

```
df<-structure(list(cy1.CSV = c("cy1.CSV", "cy24.CSV", "cy6.CSV"), 
    cy2.CSV = c("cy2.CSV", NA, NA), cy24.CSV = c("cy1.CSV", "cy24.CSV", 
    "cy6.CSV"), cy3.CSV = c("cy3.CSV", NA, NA), cy6.CSV = c("cy1.CSV", 
    "cy24.CSV", "cy6.CSV"), dlt.CSV = c("dlt.CSV", NA, NA), dm.CSV = c("dm.CSV", 
    NA, NA), dov.CSV = c("dov.CSV", "dov_1.CSV", NA), dov_1.CSV = c("dov_1.CSV", 
    NA, NA), ds.CSV = c("ds.CSV", "ds_1.CSV", NA), ds_1.CSV = c("ds.CSV", 
    "ds_1.CSV", NA)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Is it way we can find cases that fulfill: A ∈ B, but B ∉ A, in out example. dov.CSV belong to dov_1.CSV, dov_1.SCV not belong to dov.CSV. Maybe find a way to put what we find into a list or data.frame.

Comment: Do you want to reorder the columns based on the values?

Comment: I try to find out  a data set should be append to another or merge to another. So I compare the varlist from tow datasets. if A ∈ B, and B ∈ A, we append, but if A ∈ B, B ∉ A, we merge.

Comment: It may be that you want to use a fuzzy_join that joins on substring instead of an exact match

Comment: Thanks for introduce fuzzy_join package. Leaning from you everyday! :)

Answer (score 1):

We can use the column names of `df` to check whether each file is `%in%` each column inside an `sapply`. This will give us a square matrix which tells us whether each file contains every other file.

This way, it is straightforward to use array indexing to get the files which contain other files:

```r
tab <- `rownames<-`(sapply(df, function(x) names(df) %in% x), names(df))
ind <- which(tab, arr.ind = TRUE)
AinB <- data.frame(item = names(df)[ind[,2]], contains = names(df)[ind[,1]])

AinB
#>         item  contains
#> 1    cy1.CSV   cy1.CSV
#> 2    cy1.CSV  cy24.CSV
#> 3    cy1.CSV   cy6.CSV
#> 4    cy2.CSV   cy2.CSV
#> 5   cy24.CSV   cy1.CSV
#> 6   cy24.CSV  cy24.CSV
#> 7   cy24.CSV   cy6.CSV
#> 8    cy3.CSV   cy3.CSV
#> 9    cy6.CSV   cy1.CSV
#> 10   cy6.CSV  cy24.CSV
#> 11   cy6.CSV   cy6.CSV
#> 12   dlt.CSV   dlt.CSV
#> 13    dm.CSV    dm.CSV
#> 14   dov.CSV   dov.CSV
#> 15   dov.CSV dov_1.CSV
#> 16 dov_1.CSV dov_1.CSV
#> 17    ds.CSV    ds.CSV
#> 18    ds.CSV  ds_1.CSV
#> 19  ds_1.CSV    ds.CSV
#> 20  ds_1.CSV  ds_1.CSV
```

To find instances in which A is in B but not vice versa, we do the same thing except we are looking for the indices where `tab` is different from its transpose:

```r
ind2 <- which(tab & !t(tab), arr.ind = TRUE)
AinBnotBinA <- data.frame(item = names(df)[ind2[,2]], 
                          contains = names(df)[ind2[,1]])

AinBnotBinA
#>      item  contains
#> 1 dov.CSV dov_1.CSV
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>